# EF Core Base Class and TPH Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

If I have the following classes:

```
  public class Entity<TEntity>
  {
    public virtual TEntity Id { get; set; }
  }

  public class Author : Entity<Guid>
  {
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

I am using EF Core with Code First and do not override any EF configuration in "OnModelCreating()".I am currently reading "*Programming Entity Framework: Code First"* and if I am understanding correctly this should be mapped to the database with Table Per Hierarchy (TPH). TPH mapping is supposed to add a discriminator column to the DB, however when the DB is created using the entities above there is no discriminator column. Why is a discriminator column not being added for this example, but will be added for other inherited types?

Comment: If your derived `DbContext` contains something like `public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }`, it's not considered to be any of the EF inheritance patterns. I think you are misreading the concept. EF inheritance apply when you model your entity class hierarchy around a single `DbSet<BaseEntity>`. Also note that the base class cannot be generic.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for your reply. My derived DbContext is how you described. I believe you have cleared up the source of my confusion, thanks!